# Downloading csv files listed in a text file stored in a url(bash script)

Tags: bash, csv, url, download

the instructions are:
The script should download a file called filelist.txt from the base URL. It will have the full URL of https://cs1007web.teaching.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Coursework/A02/data/filelist.txt but your script should build this URL by combining the filename (filelist.txt) with the second command-line argument.

filelist.txt contains a list of files that your script must download to the data/ directory. Each file can be downloaded in the same way as filelist.txt: by appending it to the base URL.

```
Space characters () are not permitted in URLs – you must replace them with the string %20 before they will work.
```

My problem is thatit downloads index.html files instead of csv.
Please reply as soon as possible/

I've tried doing it this way but it is not dowloading what i need it to.

```
#where $2 is url given as argument and $1 is directory given by argument.
wget $2/filelist.txt
while read line; do
 wget $2 > $1/data
done < filelist.txt
```

Thanks!